# Have Keccak (SHA-3) example hashes (test vectors) been made available?

Tags: unit-testing, sha, sha-3, keccak

I'm interested in implementing Keccak (SHA-3) and would like a set of input/expected output pairs to test against. Have any official test vectors been released? I recall having some for the other SHA routines and they were very helpful.

Comment: NOTE: SHA-3 is not standardized as of this writing. It will use Keccak, but NIST hasn't published any specification for which rates to use etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. See the "Known-answer and Monte Carlo test results" bullet on the [downloads page](http://keccak.noekeon.org/files.html), or [go straight to the file](http://keccak.noekeon.org/KeccakKAT-3.zip). There are whole-message test vectors as well as files describing inputs and outputs for the individual intermediate stages.

And of course, you can always run the reference implementation and compare outputs.

Answer (score 2):

> Have Keccak (SHA-3) example hashes (test vectors) been made available?

Yes. The NIST test vectors can be found at [SHA-3 Reference and Optimized Implementations](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Submission_Reqs/test_vectors.html). The page includes:

- [Description of Known Answer Test (KAT) and Monte Carlo Test (MCT) for SHA-3 Candidate Algorithm Submissions](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/SHA3-KATMCT1.pdf)
- [Test files and Source Code for Conducting KAT and MCT](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/documents/KAT1.zip)

These tests may be different from the Keccak test vectors because NIST modified some things. So, for SHA-3, I would specifically use what NIST provides.